# Design matrix for random effect for animal model

Tags: r

I am trying do to a design matrix in R for animal effect.
I have a pedigree file and a data file.

Data file(2 columns, one for animal id and one for trait - milk yield in this case):

```
AnimalID    Trait
2           10
COWX1       11 
3           22
RO500       13
ANGUS50X    12
```

PED file(3 columns, first is animal id, second is mother id and last father id):

```
AnimalID  MotherID  FatherID
7         0         0
10        0         0
2         0         0 
COWX1     7         10
5         7         0
3         0         10
RO500     2         0
ANGUS50X  COWX1     0
```

In the end I want to obtain this design matrix:

```
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

The matrix has 5 rows and 8 columns. 5 rows because there are 5 animals with recorded trait and 8 columns because all the animals are 8.

In this moment I use a function to obtain the design matrix, but it is working only if I recode the Animals. The code should start from 1 and should be consecutively.

Example :

Animal 7 is 1, 10 is 2, 2 is 3, COWX1 is 4, 5 is 5, 3 is 6, RO500 is 7 and ANGUS50X is 8.

I do not want to recode and I want to use the Animal ID that I get from the farmers.

Function that I use now:

```
 animal <- factor(c(3,4,6,7,8), levels=1:8)
 model.matrix(~ animal + 0)
```

Can anybody help me in this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Please reshape your question, and provide your examples using `dput` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suppose you need change the column and row names of the design matrix

```
ani<- read.table(text = "
AnimalID    Trait
2           10
COWX1       11 
3           22
RO500       13
ANGUS50X    12", header = TRUE)

PED <- read.table(text = "
AnimalID  MotherID  FatherID
7         0         0
10        0         0
2         0         0 
COWX1     7         10
5         7         0
3         0         10
RO500     2         0
ANGUS50X  COWX1     0", header = TRUE)


animal <- factor(ani$AnimalID, levels=PED$Animal)

dm <- model.matrix(~ animal + 0)
rownames(dm) <- ani$AnimalID
colnames(dm) <- PED$AnimalID
dm
```

The result as follows:

```
         7 10 2 COWX1 5 3 RO500 ANGUS50X
2        0  0 1     0 0 0     0        0
COWX1    0  0 0     1 0 0     0        0
3        0  0 0     0 0 1     0        0
RO500    0  0 0     0 0 0     1        0
ANGUS50X 0  0 0     0 0 0     0        1
```